# Questions about my C program skipping blank lines

Tags: c, pointers, line, stdout

I have a `main` function that works perfectly. It passes a pointer to a `FILE` to my `readFile` function and it is supposed to output the data of the file and removes the blank lines. What happens is it outputs every single line **including** the blank lines. I have thoroughly checked my code and I can not seem to find a problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
int
check_whitespace (char *line)
{
  while (*line)
    {
      if (!('\n' == *line || '\t' == *line || ' ' == *line))
        return 0;
      line += 1;
    }
  return 1; /* returns 1 if line is ALL blanks */
}


int
readFile (FILE * fp)
{
  char arrbuff[BUFFSIZE];
  while (fgets (arrbuff, BUFFSIZE, fp) != NULL)
    if (!check_whitespace (arrbuff))
      { /* 0 = goodline */
        fputs (arrbuff, stdout);
      }
  fclose (fp);
}
```

Comment: The code shown works perfectly. If you want us to fix it, you'll have to show us something broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
if (!('\n' == *line || '\t' == *line || ' ' == *line))
    return 0;
```

in your code to

```
if (!isspace(*line))
    return 0;
```

You'll need to add

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

I'm guessing you are running under Windows, and each line ends in `\r\n` and you aren't picking up the `\r`.

From the man page:

> **`isspace()`** checks  for  white-space  characters.  In the "C" and "POSIX" locales, these are: space, form-feed (`'\f'`), newline (`'\n'`), carriage return (`'\r'`), horizontal tab (`'\t'`), and vertical tab (`'\v'`).

Even if this doesn't fix it, it would make your code far more readable.

Alternatively, for a minimal change:

```
if (!('\n' == *line || '\t' == *line || ' ' == *line || '\r' == *line))
    return 0;
```

Comment: Readable, yes, Fixed, no. The code shown already works perfectly.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker well perhaps it works for you (as it does for me on Linux) but it won't work under Windows as it won't detect the `\r` as a blank character. This is my guess as to what the issue is (per the above); every line will appear non-blank. This fixes it.

Comment: Ah, Windows. That might be it. But doesn't even Windows handle '\n' properly if the file is opened in non-binary mode?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker we're not shown how he's opened it.